# How to associate an text to image in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I have a simple question to be asked here . I have created a working random generator at here :

```js
var randPics = document.querySelector("#randPics");
var getPics = document.querySelector(".getPics");


getPics.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
//array to store images for the random image generator
var picsGallery = new Array();
    picsGallery = ["https://static2.jetpens.com/images/a/000/026/26648.jpg?mark64=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5qZXRwZW5zLmNvbS9pbWFnZXMvYXNzZXRzL3dhdGVybWFyay5wbmc&markalign64=dG9wLHJpZ2h0&markscale=19&s=938428f6eca690069a86f66d0754444b",
"http://assets.sajiansedap.com/media/article_image/cover/large/25505-cara-memilih-nanas-yang-matang.jpg",
 "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1030/8703/products/epal-hijau-green-apple-each-sebiji_1024x1024.jpg?v=1487817043"]
 
 //generate random no to select the random images
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * picsGallery.length);
//change the pics locations of the source
  randPics.src=picsGallery[rnd]
  });
```

```css
#randPics{
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>Display a random image each time the buttons is clicked!</p>
<p> You get a <span id="text"></span>  </p>

<button class="getPics"> Click ! </button>
<br>
<img id="randPics" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/45447-200.png">

</body>
```

When user clicked on the button, the image source will randomly select one of the images in the array. However, I have a tiny bit of problem. How do I associate text to the images ? For example , if the user click the button and he get the images of pen , the text

> You get a

should change to

> You get a **pen.**

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, you need to store the text somewhere and then you must have a way to associate the text to images, for this you can store the text associated with images in an object and then have an array of such objects instead of just an array of images urls. Also you need not declare the array inside the event handler function, you can define it once and then use it inside the function as it will be in the scope. something like this:

```js
var randPics = document.querySelector("#randPics");
var getPics = document.querySelector(".getPics");
var textElem = document.querySelector("#text");

//array to store images for the random image generator
var picsGallery = picsGallery = [{img: "https://static2.jetpens.com/images/a/000/026/26648.jpg?mark64=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5qZXRwZW5zLmNvbS9pbWFnZXMvYXNzZXRzL3dhdGVybWFyay5wbmc&markalign64=dG9wLHJpZ2h0&markscale=19&s=938428f6eca690069a86f66d0754444b", text:'pen'},
{img: "http://assets.sajiansedap.com/media/article_image/cover/large/25505-cara-memilih-nanas-yang-matang.jpg", text:'pineapple'},
 {img: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1030/8703/products/epal-hijau-green-apple-each-sebiji_1024x1024.jpg?v=1487817043", text:'apple'}];

getPics.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
   
 //generate random no to select the random images
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * picsGallery.length);
//change the pics locations of the source
  randPics.src=picsGallery[rnd].img;
  text.innerHTML = picsGallery[rnd].text;
  });
```

```css
#randPics{
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>Display a random image each time the buttons is clicked!</p>
<p> You get a <span id="text"></span>  </p>

<button class="getPics"> Click ! </button>
<br>
<img id="randPics" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/45447-200.png">

</body>
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't see that, it was already part of code, thanks for pointing, I have corrected code.

Comment: Hi @Dij , thank you for your answer . But since from beginning, I was self taught that to declare a new array, we need to declare var element = new Array(); but I learnt something new that array can be declared directly.

Comment: @AlanKohW.T yes you have to declare it but you don't need to declare it inside the event handler here, declare it outside the event handler.

Comment: ah I see what you meant. If we declare outside of event handler, we can reuse the said array for other event handlers. Right ? The D.R.Y principles. Sorry about it, I am very new to programming

Comment: Ok, done but since my reputation is less than 15, S.O locked my voting ability but I think I already accept your answer as solved. :) Thanks again for your time, Dij and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Define `picsGallery` array outside of event handler.

You can define an array containing two elements for each each element of `picsGallery` array. Set `<img>` `.src` to `picsGallery[rnd][0]`, and `#text` `.textContent` to `picsGallery[rnd][1]`

```js
var randPics = document.querySelector("#randPics");
var getPics = document.querySelector(".getPics");
var text = document.querySelector("#text");

var picsGallery = [
  ["https://static2.jetpens.com/images/a/000/026/26648.jpg?mark64=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5qZXRwZW5zLmNvbS9pbWFnZXMvYXNzZXRzL3dhdGVybWFyay5wbmc&markalign64=dG9wLHJpZ2h0&markscale=19&s=938428f6eca690069a86f66d0754444b", "pen"],
  ["http://assets.sajiansedap.com/media/article_image/cover/large/25505-cara-memilih-nanas-yang-matang.jpg", "pineapple"],
  ["https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1030/8703/products/epal-hijau-green-apple-each-sebiji_1024x1024.jpg?v=1487817043", "apple"]
];

getPics.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * picsGallery.length);
  //change the pics locations of the source
  randPics.src = picsGallery[rnd][0];
  text.textContent = picsGallery[rnd][1];
});
```

```css
#randPics {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Display a random image each time the buttons is clicked!</p>
  <p> You get a <span id="text"></span> </p>

  <button class="getPics"> Click ! </button>
  <br>
  <img id="randPics" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/45447-200.png">

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code a bit - associated all images with a text and stored them inside JavaScript object, instead of array. The rest is almost what you've write.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
<style type="text/css">

    #randPics{
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      align-content: center;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <body>
    <p>Display a random image each time the buttons is clicked!</p>
    <p> You get a <span id="text"></span>  </p>

    <button class="getPics"> Click ! </button>
    <br>
    <img id="randPics" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/45447-200.png">

<script>
    var randPics = document.querySelector("#randPics");
    var getPics = document.querySelector(".getPics");


    getPics.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    //array to store images for the random image generator
    var picsGallery =  {"bar": "https://static2.jetpens.com/images/a/000/026/26648.jpg?mark64=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5qZXRwZW5zLmNvbS9pbWFnZXMvYXNzZXRzL3dhdGVybWFyay5wbmc&markalign64=dG9wLHJpZ2h0&markscale=19&s=938428f6eca690069a86f66d0754444b", "foo":
    "http://assets.sajiansedap.com/media/article_image/cover/large/25505-cara-memilih-nanas-yang-matang.jpg",
     "tux":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1030/8703/products/epal-hijau-green-apple-each-sebiji_1024x1024.jpg?v=1487817043"}
     
     //generate random no to select the random images
    var gkeys = Object.keys(picsGallery);
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * gkeys.length);
    //change the pics locations of the source
      randPics.src=picsGallery[gkeys[rnd]]
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = gkeys[rnd];  
      });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before we start talking about computer vision etc. lets keep this simple:

The easiest way to this is by having some relation between two sets of data. The datasets we have are:

1. Text: A description of the subject.
2. Link: A link to an image representing the subject.

In some cases, some information about the subject (green-apple) can be extracted from the link, however we would need to find a structure in the links (or some kind of dictionary) to be able to parse it.

A simple solution would be to swap your array of links for an array of objects with 2 keys:

- Text
- Link

Picking a random entry in that array would give you instant access to the both the text and link. This is also the cleanest solution as it allows you to add more fields as you go.